How to Reduce Cold Start Time for AWS Lambda with Heavy Library Imports (SQLAlchemy, etc.)?
I'm working with AWS Lambda in a serverless environment and I'm facing significant cold start delays due to heavy library imports before my handler. My Lambda function needs to use libraries like SQLAlchemy, which takes around 0.4 seconds just to import. Combined with other library imports, my cold start time can reach up to 1.3 seconds.
This is a critical issue because one Lambda function often calls another, and both are subject to cold starts. This can result in an initial request taking 3-4 seconds to complete, which is far from ideal for my use case.
Here's an example of some of the imports I have before my handler:
import time
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from some_other_library import heavy_import

# Other imports...

def my_handler(event, context):
    # Function logic...
    pass

What I've Tried:

Lazy Loading: I've considered importing libraries only when needed, but some are required during initialization.

AWS Lambda Layers: I'm already using layers to reduce the package size, but this doesn't seem to affect the import time during cold starts.

Increased Memory Size: I increased the allocated memory for the Lambda function, but this did not reduce the cold start time.


Question: How can I further reduce the cold start time in AWS Lambda, particularly with heavy library imports like SQLAlchemy? Are there any best practices or patterns for dealing with this issue in a serverless architecture?
Is the only solution to keep the lambda hot? Using a CloudWatchEvent or something similar
Why do these libraries take so long to load? I find it crazy that it takes almost 1 second to load libraries...

One Lambda function invoking a 2nd Lambda function synchronously is not ideal and should be avoided if you can. Investigate the benefit of higher RAM configuration for your Lambda function as that will increase available CPU and reduce import times. And try to use lightweight libraries.

Cool effort to do trial and error, but i have some suggestions here.

Can we change into a lightweight alternatives library? like psycopg2?.

Yes you can keep warm lambda by using cloudwatch event rule, this cool post you may like


source: https://www.pluralsight.com/resources/blog/cloud/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm#:~:text=Keep%20Lambda%20warm%20by%20using,minutes%20to%20keep%20it%20warm.
or you can put this extra package to your function if you use javascript.
source: https://github.com/jeremydaly/lambda-warmer

If your lambda needs low latency and consistent performance are critical, and you're willing to invest in higher costs. you can use lambda provisioned concurrency.

source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html#configuring-provisioned-concurrency
